# errno after accept in Linux socket programming

Tags: c, linux, sockets, error-handling

As stated in `accept()` man page in `RETURN VALUE` section:

> **Error handling**
>   Linux `accept()` (and `accept4()`) passes already-pending network errors on the new socket as an error code from `accept()`.  This behavior  differs from other BSD socket implementations.  For reliable operation the application should detect the network errors defined for the protocol after `accept()` and treat them like `EAGAIN` by retrying.  In the case of TCP/IP, these  are  `ENETDOWN`,  `EPROTO`,  `ENOPROTOOPT`,  `EHOSTDOWN`, `ENONET`, `EHOSTUNREACH`, `EOPNOTSUPP`, and `ENETUNREACH`.

Does this mean one must check the value of `errno` right after the `accept()` returns and before checking the return value of `accept()` ? if yes, and if `errno` is set what steps must be taken?

here's a snippet of my code handling `accept()` :

```
newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);
if((errno == ENETDOWN || errno == EPROTO || errno == ENOPROTOOPT || errno == EHOSTDOWN ||
    errno == ENONET || errno == EHOSTUNREACH || errno == EOPNOTSUPP || errno == ENETUNREACH))
    return;
if (newsockfd < 0)
{
    // error
}
else if(newsockfd > 0)
{
    // accepted a new connection
}
else
{
    // blah blah blah
}
```

I have concluded that in this case one might try again in a while. Is my conclusion correct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, you check `accept()` return value. If `accept()` return value is less than `0`, then you should check `errno`. If it is `ENETDOWN`, `EPROTO`,  `ENOPROTOOPT`, `EHOSTDOWN`, `ENONET`, `EHOSTUNREACH`, `EOPNOTSUPP`, or `ENETUNREACH`, then you may call `accept()` again. Otherwise something bad has happened and you should stop calling `accept()` (you've passed bad listen socket as `accept()`'s parameter, for example).

That's how I understand the code.

And here is how the error handling may be done:

```
while (running) {
    newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);
    if (newsockfd < 0)
    {
        // error
        perror ("accept");
        if((errno == ENETDOWN || errno == EPROTO || errno == ENOPROTOOPT || errno == EHOSTDOWN ||
            errno == ENONET || errno == EHOSTUNREACH || errno == EOPNOTSUPP || errno == ENETUNREACH)) {
            continue;
         }
         exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // accepted a new connection
    // blah blah blah
}
```

Comment: so if the `errno` is not equal to any of the checked values do we have to close the `sockfd` file descriptor and open a new one? what about `cli_addr`?

Comment: Never see what someone reopen `sockfd` after accept failed.  `sockfd` is a listen socket returned from `bind`. What could happen to it after it was created? Never see that. cli_addr is

Comment: Also you have to check for `EAGAIN` and `EWOULDBLOCK` for listen socket sockets opened with `O_NONBLOCK ` and call accept again.

Comment: ok, does this mean I have to do the same in case of `read()` too?

Comment: `read()` will return different error codes, unrelated to accept. If you get `EAGAIN` or `EWOULDBLOCK` from read, than you could call `read()` again later. If `read()` return anything else, than that's fatal error and you have to close `newsockfd`. And also `read()` returns 0 if connection successfully closed by peer.

Comment: `exit (EXIT_FAILURE);` kills the process. It looks like a very strong measure due a unmapped errno after accept(). For real applications, a better approach could be closing `sockfd` and try to reopen it.

Answer (score 3):

According to [SUSv4](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/accept.html):

> Upon successful completion, `accept()` shall return the non-negative file descriptor of the accepted socket. Otherwise, `-1` shall be returned and `errno` set to indicate the error.

This means that you only need to check `errno` if `accept()` returns `-1`.

Your code might look more like this:

```
ret = accept(fd, &addr, sizeof (addr));
if (ret == -1) {
    switch (errno) {
    case EAGAIN:
    case EWOULDBLOCK:
        /* do something */
        break;
    case EBADF:
        /* do something different */
        break;
    default:
        /* do something even more different */
    }
}
```

(How exactly you handle each error condition will depend on your application.)

Also, it is important to check `errno` *immediately* after checking the return value of `accept()`. If you call any other functions first (even a simple `fprintf()`), you risk overwriting `errno` with a different error.

Comment: I've up voted your answer for reminding to check `errno` immediately before doing anything that could change it.

Answer (score 0):

You should handle `EHOSTUNREACH` as well, which shows 'Software caused connection abort'.

I handled `accept()` return value as the accepted answer did, but one of my servers crashes because of `EHOSTUNREACH`. 
After google, I realize that the socket credentials has not been changed after `ECONNABORTED` error likewise. We shouldn't crash the program just for `ECONNABORTED`.

And its various constraints is as follow:

1. If the connection hasn't been established yet, i.e., if it is the very first request from the client and if the client closes the connection even before the server got a chance to respond, accept() call at server results in `ECONNABORTED`. Server should ignore this error and move on with the next request in the queue. If the client needs to connect to the server again, it has to do another connect().
2. If the connection between client and server is in ESTABLISHED state, and if the client closes the connection abruptly, accept() call at server results in `ECONNABORTED`. In this scenario, the server must close the connection that is half-open. Otherwise those half-opened sockets may remain in CLOSE_WAIT state, as long as the server process is active. Have a look at this web page: http://technopark02.blogspot.com/200...closewait.html, to know more about CLOSE_WAIT and its impact, in a slightly different scenario.

Finally, complete code is as follow:

```
while(running)
{
    sfd = accept(socketFd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &addr_len);
    if( sfd < 0)
    {
        if (errno == EWOULDBLOCK || errno == EAGAIN || errno == ENONET ||
            errno == EPROTO || errno == ENOPROTOOPT || errno == EOPNOTSUPP ||
            errno == ENETDOWN || errno == ENETUNREACH || errno == EHOSTDOWN ||
            errno == EHOSTUNREACH || errno == ECONNABORTED)
        {
            log_warn("accept error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
            break;
        }
        else if( errno == EINTR)
        {
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            log_error("AccepCb: accept error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
            assert(false);
        }
    }

    // logical works...
}
```